# Cannot animate UIImageview

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview

My issue is that when I press the button that runs the dealToPlayer function(), everything acts as if a card has been dealt, updates total value of cards dealt, but it does not show any animation of the card being dealt or placed. Why might this be? I am not using auto layout for this scene at all.

```
  func dealToPlayer() {

    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(deckCards.count)))
    let drawnCard = deckCards.remove(at: index)
    randomCards.append(drawnCard)


    randomCard = randomCards[3 + cardSelect]

    image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.deckLocation.x, y: self.deckLocation.y, width: self.width, height: self.height))
    image.image = mapping[randomCard]



    cardsOut = cardsOut + 1
    print("cards out is currently: \(cardsOut)")
    cardSelect = cardSelect + 1

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1.5, options: [], animations: {
        self.image.frame = CGRect(x: self.cardTwoLocation.x - (self.cardsOut * self.thirdWidth), y: self.cardTwoLocation.y, width: self.width, height: self.height)
        }, completion: nil)



    checkPlayerValue()

}
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: No, I am not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your image view is added to your view controller.

Second, make sure your animation is called by putting a break point.

Third, print out the location and make sure the new x and y are valid, and they are different than the previous x and y.

Here is a sample duplicate of your code an it works fine

```
image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
image.backgroundColor = .red

self.view.addSubview(image)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1.5, options: [], animations: {
    self.image.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
}, completion: nil)
```

[image]